# Call AWS API Gateway from Flask server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, aws-lambda, jwt

I am using [flask-cognito-lib](https://mblackgeo.github.io/flask-cognito-lib/) and AWS Cognito to authentical users. I am able to follow the example code to secure Flask endpoints.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, redirect, session, url_for

from flask_cognito_lib import CognitoAuth
from flask_cognito_lib.decorators import (
    auth_required,
    cognito_login,
    cognito_login_callback,
    cognito_logout,
)

app = Flask(__name__)

# Configuration required for CognitoAuth
app.config["AWS_REGION"] = "eu-west-1"
app.config["AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID"] = "eu-west-1_qwerty"
app.config["AWS_COGNITO_DOMAIN"] = "https://app.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com"
app.config["AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID"] = "asdfghjkl1234asdf"
app.config["AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_SECRET"] = "zxcvbnm1234567890"
app.config["AWS_COGNITO_REDIRECT_URL"] = "https://example.com/postlogin"
app.config["AWS_COGNITO_LOGOUT_URL"] = "https://example.com/postlogout"

auth = CognitoAuth(app)


@app.route("/login")
@cognito_login
def login():
    # A simple route that will redirect to the Cognito Hosted UI.
    # No logic is required as the decorator handles the redirect to the Cognito
    # hosted UI for the user to sign in.
    pass


@app.route("/postlogin")
@cognito_login_callback
def postlogin():
    # A route to handle the redirect after a user has logged in with Cognito.
    # This route must be set as one of the User Pool client's Callback URLs in
    # the Cognito console and also as the config value AWS_COGNITO_REDIRECT_URL.
    # The decorator will store the validated access token in a HTTP only cookie
    # and the user claims and info are stored in the Flask session:
    # session["claims"] and session["user_info"].
    # Do anything login after the user has logged in here, e.g. a redirect
    return redirect(url_for("claims"))


@app.route("/claims")
@auth_required()
def claims():
    # This route is protected by the Cognito authorisation. If the user is not
    # logged in at this point or their token from Cognito is no longer valid
    # a 401 Authentication Error is thrown, which is caught here a redirected
    # to login.
    # If their session is valid, the current session will be shown including
    # their claims and user_info extracted from the Cognito tokens.
    return jsonify(session)


@app.route("/admin")
@auth_required(groups=["admin"])
def admin():
    # This route will only be accessible to a user who is a member of all of
    # groups specified in the "groups" argument on the auth_required decorator
    # If they are not, a CognitoGroupRequiredError is raised which is handled
    # below
    return jsonify(session["claims"]["cognito:groups"])


@app.route("/logout")
@cognito_logout
def logout():
    # Logout of the Cognito User pool and delete the cookies that were set
    # on login.
    # No logic is required here as it simply redirects to Cognito.
    pass


@app.route("/postlogout")
def postlogout():
    # This is the endpoint Cognito redirects to after a user has logged out,
    # handle any logic here, like returning to the homepage.
    # This route must be set as one of the User Pool client's Sign Out URLs.
    return redirect(url_for("home"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Now  I have created an AWS Lambda with API Endpoint trigger

```
API endpoint: https://<endpoint ID>.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com/default/<endpoint-name>
Details
API type: HTTP
Authorization: JWT
Authorizer ID: <auth-ID>
CORS: No
Detailed metrics enabled: No
Method: ANY
Resource path: /<endpoint-name>
Service principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
Stage: default
Statement ID: <stmt-ID>
```

How can I call this endpoint from Flask/Python?

Comment: Didn't get your question properly are you trying to deploy flask on AWS lambda and trying to call your custom endpoint(login,postlogin etc)? Or lambda contain different code?

Comment: @SmitParmar I deploy flask server on Elastic Beanstalk. But I also created an AWS Lambda. I want to call that Lambda from flask. Without enabling authorization, I could simply make a request to the API endpoint. But with authorization is required I have no clue how to call that lambda. Actually it doesn't even matter where the flask is deployed. I'm testing it locally anyway. And it may not necessarily even matter that it's flask. How do I call that Lambda from Python at all?

Comment: Did you tried using `requests` module ?. Like `requests.get(Endpoint)` . Make sure your lambda properly integrated with API gateway.

Comment: @SmitParmar I get `Forbidden`. How do I pass the JWT token?

Comment: You need to pass header while making request.  `headers={"Authorization":"your token"}`. Something like this. `requests.get(Endpoint,headers=headers)`. You can refer some blog on this.